# How to check trip start-date and end-date with start-time and end-time in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working on Booking system where a user can book their cars, before adding any trip inside the database/table I want to check the trip already exist between the dates and times.
Here is my query inside my model.

```
$this->db->select('trId')
->from('trips')              
->where('carId',$data['carId'])//car Id
 ->where('tripStart <=',$data['tripStart'])//trip start date
->where('tripEnd >= ',$data['tripEnd'])//trip end date
->where('tripStartTime <= ',$data['tripStartTime'])//trip start time
->where('tripStartEnd >=',$data['tripStartEnd'])//trip end time
->get();
```

I have stored the values in my trips table is

```
tripStart = '2018-03-01'
tripEnd = '2018-03-03'
tripStartTime = '09:00:00'
tripStartEnd = '13:00:00'
```

Comment: now what is the issue?

Comment: I am confused how can i compare my new trips with exist trips date and time in the database

Answer (score 1):

```
select trId from trips 
where carId = value AND 
      (Between tripStart = "value" AND tripEnd = "value") AND
      (Between tripsStartTime = "value" AND tripStartEnd = "value");
```

This that What you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but before that you have to concate sql columns for comparing
Know `SQL` `CONCAT`

Also you need to combine your variables using into datetime using `strtotime` PHP function

```
<?php    
    $tripStart = '2018-03-01';
    $tripEnd = '2018-03-03';
    $tripStartTime = '09:00:00';
    $tripStartEnd = '13:00:00';

    $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($tripStart.$tripStartTime));
    $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($tripEnd.$tripStartEnd));

    $this->db->select('trId')
    ->from('trips')              
    ->where('carId',1)//car Id
    ->where("CONCAT(tripStart,'',tripStartTime) > ",$from)
    ->where("CONCAT(tripEnd,'',tripStartEnd) < ",$to)
    ->get();
?>
```